# Does the prefix "er-" imply an action was successful?

Tags: standard-german

Do verbs with an “er-“ prefix imply that the action is successful? (ie, do “ersuchen” and “erbitten,” for example, imply that the thing requested was given or gained?) If so, is that also the case for the prefixes “be-“ and “ver-" used in the same fashion?

Answer (score 4):

No, they don't.

*Erbitten* is simply used in a slightly different fashion than *bitten*.

> Er bittet sie um die Autoschlüssel.

They may be his car keys, actually.

> Er erbittet ihre Autoschlüssel.

They are her car keys.

Sometimes you want one variant, sometimes the other.

The verb *ersuchen* is a very formal, odd, and old-fashioned variant of *erbitten*.

---

In general, the way how prefixes change a verb is very complicated. You can make out rules as soon you know the verbs and the exceptions. Which means these rules won't help you at all.

Comment: Not just *ersuchen*, also *erbitten* is marked as *gehoben* (formal) or *veraltend* (being outdated) by [Duden.de](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erbitten)

Answer (score 2):

I confine my answer to the part about *er-*.

**short answer**

No.

**little longer answer**

Sometimes adding the prefix *er-* changes the meaning of the verb.

> e.g. erachten erbrechen erbringen ereignen erfahren erfassen erfragen erfüllen ergeben ergehen ergründen erhalten erheben erholen erlassen erlauben erläutern erlegen erliegen erlösen ermäßigen ermessen ernennen eröffnen erpressen erreichen errichten ersaufen erschaffen ersetzen erstarren erstehen erstellen ersticken erstrecken ersuchen erteilen ertragen ertrinken erwägen erwähnen erweichen erweisen erwerben erwischen erzählen erziehen

Sometimes it doesn't change anything.

> e.g. erahnen erbauen erbitten erflehen erfolgen erforschen erfreuen erklären erlernen ermahnen ermangeln ermorden ernähren erproben erretten erschrecken ersehnen erstaunen erstrahlen erstreben erwarten erwehren

Sometimes the *er-* has something to do with the start of something.

> e.g. erblühen erfinden erfordern erkennen erklingen erlahmen erleiden erregen erröten erwachen

And sometimes it's a mix of the above or you can't even really tell, if the root-word is a verb or adjective. *Röten* e.g. means to make something *rot* and *rot* is an adjective.

**Sometimes** though success is implied.

> e.g. erdenken erdrosseln erdrücken erdulden ereilen erfrieren ergaunern ergreifen erhängen erhärten erhaschen erklettern erleben erleuchten errechnen erreichen erringen erschießen erschließen erschöpfen ersinnen erspähen ersparen erstechen ertappen ertönen erwärmen erwecken erwirken erwirtschaften erwürgen erzeugen

The distribution of all of the (random) example words looks like this:

[image: distribution of sample words]

If a verb is made by adding *er-* to an adjective, the meaning often implies success.

> e.g. erfrischen ergänzen erheitern erhellen erkalten erleichtern ermächtigen ermatten ermöglichen ermüden ermuntern ermutigen erneuern erniedrigen ernüchtern erschlaffen erschweren erstarken erübrigen erweitern

But even with adjectives there are exceptions like *ledig - erledigen*, *lang - erlangen* or it's just wishing instead of success like in *kundig - erkundigen*.

So finally: **no!** Interesting question though.

Comment: Instead of *success* I would say, *er-* implies that you gain something by doing something. *erfrischen* - gain *Frische* by doing *erfrischen*, *ergänzen* - gain *Ganzheit* by doing *ergänzen*, *erstarken* - get *Stärke*, and so on

Comment: And, btw, *erlangen* is not (directly) derived from the adjective *lang*, but from the verb *langen*, I'd say.

Comment: Yes, success is meant here like OP explained in his question (to gain). (How would *erhängen* refer to success?) *Erlangen* shows, that you can't just add *er-* to an adjective and get a verb that implies "success" automatically.

Comment: Yes. I would also put *erröten*, *erleiden*, *erfinden*, *erbitten*, *erflehen*, *erzeugen*, *erringen* into this category of "gaining something"